# How to loop with 2 number sequence

Tags: r, data.table

I have a set of data frames named list2008, list2009... to list2017, all with same columns. I am merging these data frames with the following chunky codes:

```
byvar = c("A","B","C")
tmp1 = merge(list2008, list2009, all = TRUE,by = byvar)
tmp2 = merge(tmp1, list2010, all = TRUE,by = byvar)
tmp3 = merge(tmp2, list2011, all = TRUE,by = byvar)
tmp4 = merge(tmp3, list2012, all = TRUE,by = byvar)
tmp5 = merge(tmp4, list2013, all = TRUE,by = byvar)
tmp6 = merge(tmp5, list2014, all = TRUE,by = byvar)
tmp7 = merge(tmp6, list2015, all = TRUE,by = byvar)
tmp8 = merge(tmp7, list2016, all = TRUE,by = byvar)
agg = merge(tmp8, list2017, all = TRUE,by = byvar)
```

I'm wondering if there is a more elegant way using loop to achieve agg. Thanks.

Comment: check join_all function from dplyr package

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091303/simultaneously-merge-multiple-data-frames-in-a-list)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `bind_rows` function from `dplyr` to merge all data.frames. The steps are:
1. Add all data frames in a list
2. Use `bind_rows` function to merge data frames having common columns

Lets take an example.

```
## The data
df1 <- data.frame(id = c(1:10), name = c(LETTERS[1:10]), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df2 <- data.frame(id = 11:20, name = LETTERS[11:20], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
df3 <- data.frame(id = 21:30, name = LETTERS[15:24], stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

Create list of all data.frames. 
z1 <- list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)

# Merge with bind_rows
merge <- bind_rows(z1)

#Result -- combined data
#> merge 
#   id name
#1   1    A
#2   2    B
#3   3    C
#4   4    D
#5   5    E
#6   6    F
#7   7    G
#.........
#30 30   X
```

Answer (score 0):

The bind_rows command is the fastest way:

```
bind_rows(list2008,list2009)
```

That will append list2009 under list2008 matching the columns.

Rstudio has a nice cheat sheet for using dplyr:

[Data Wrangling](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/data-wrangling-cheatsheet.pdf)